# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property of undefined with axios

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios

I have this vue.js component that uses axios to retrive a json array of `joke` objects :

```
<template>
  <div id="show-jokes-all">
        <h2>Showing all jokes</h2>
        <div v-for="joke in jokes">
                <h2>{{joke.title}}</h2>
                <article>{{joke.body}}</article>
            <hr>
        </div>  

  </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'showJokes',

      data () {
        return {
            jokes:[]

        }
      },

      methods: {

      },

      created() {
        axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/jokes).then(function(data){    
       //console.log(data); works fine
        this.jokes = data.body;
        });
    }
}
</script>
```

When I log the result in console it's fine but when I try to put it in `jokes` array I get

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot set property 'jokes' of
>   undefined

This may be a trivial error but as a newbie to vue.js I'm stock on this so appreciate your hints.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Comment: Essentially, `.then(data => this.jokes = data.body)` instead of the function you have. Or use a closure or bind as described in the above link.

Comment: @Bert, I followed this tutorial, and that's how it used data: https://youtu.be/aoWqFLGCK60?list=PL4cUxeGkcC9gQcYgjhBoeQH7wiAyZNrYa

Comment: That tutorial uses VueResource (`this.$http`) instead of `axios`. `this` is treated differently inside the callbacks of those two libraries.

Comment: I see! but using `.then(data => this.jokes = data.body)` while removes the error, but no data is being displayed. Any idea why?

Comment: What comes back in `data.body`?

Comment: an array of jokes in json format.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152195/discussion-between-bert-and-karlom).

Comment: One clarification for any future readers; I said `.then(data => this.jokes = data.body)` above, but it should have been `.then(response => this.jokes = response.data)`.

Answer (score 18):

You are out of `this` context. You should store `this` context on a variable.

```
 created() {
    let self = this
    axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/jokes').then(function(data){    
   //console.log(data); works fine
    self.jokes = data.body;
    });
}
```

There are many ways in [How to access the correct `this` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20279485)
. You can refer here for many ways.

## thanks to Bert on comments

Comment: It's 2018, there's no need to do `let self = this` anymore :)
Use an [arrow function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) instead!

`axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/jokes').then(data => {  ... });`

Answer (score 3):

yes,you can use ES6 .

```
<template>
    <div id="show-jokes-all">
        <h2>Showing all jokes</h2>
        <div v-for="joke in jokes">
            <h2>{{joke.title}}</h2>
            <article>{{joke.body}}</article>
            <hr>
        </div>  
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import axios from 'axios';
  export default {
    name: 'showJokes',
    data () {
      return {
        jokes:[]
      }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    created() {
      axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8090/api/jokes').then((data) => {    
      // console.log(data); // works fine
      this.jokes = data.body;
    });
  }
}
</script>
```